# Sentence start with "If then"

Tags: word-usage

Can any one tell me that when we start a sentence with *If then*? I came across this one.

> If then a practical end must be assigned to a university course,I say it is that of training good members of society.

Is it conditional sentence?

Comment: it would probably be:  If, then, a practical...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Then* refers to a point established previously. *If* simply re-introduces the idea in order to add to it. It might help to know that the original sentence was punctuated as *If, then, a practical...* and that it was formal writing in *1892*. That's a pretty different style of writing than today.

If it is a conditional, then I would call it a factual conditional sentence. It is akin to saying (much less formally)

> If you need to know my answer immediately, then it's *no*.

I think you might find it in very formal writing still.

Comment: It's still a conditional. It just has its condition fulfilled by the context. It simultaneously affirms the same statement as the non-conditional statement would have, *and* it affirms that it wouldn't be there were the situation different. It might also imply a certain sense of uncertainty about whether the condition really is as matter-of-fact as the collocutor seems to think: "I myself consider learning to be its own reward, but some people only ever think of mundane practicalities. If then a practical end must..." tl;dr: You imply A; I state A => B, implying B. A => B is still conditional.

Comment: @Amadan I remember a very old song (60s) that began "If it's Tuesday, this must be Belgium" and that phrase is not conditional. the "if" expresses surprise or an opinion, depending on how you interpret this line.

Comment: Yes, I was just re-reading about conditionals, and was about to change it. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I do not understand why you don't think it is a conditional. Is there a rule that conditionals cannot express surprise, or an opinion? I believe you might be unduly restricting your definition of "conditional" to causal conditional only..?

Comment: Is this the the so-called Zero conditional? And I really want to add 'd in the OP's second clause, "I'd say..." Not an easy question to answer. Amadan was right about my example, it is conditional, this is Belgium on the condition that today is Tuesday. But I'm not so sure about the OP's example.

Answer (score 0):

The first two words are not really related, and I think strictly there should be commas round *then*: you could substitute "So, if a practical end must be assigned..." It's a perfectly usual, if slightly formal, construction.